# Compare arrays with different sizes with strcmp()

Tags: c, newline, c-strings, fgets, strcmp

I'm currently learning C and I have this question...

```
char name[6] = "Pedro";
char test[25];

printf("Insert a name: ");
fgets(test, 25, stdin);

if(!strcmp(name, test))
   puts("They are equal...");
```

During the execution, strcmp doesn't return 0 when I insert the value "Pedro" in the array "test"...
I know the array "test" have a size of 25 instead of 6, but since C dettects the end of a string with '\0', how can I use the fgets in this situation?

Thank you very much...

Comment: I forgot to salute and I'm trying to edit my post but I can't, so, hello everyone!

Comment: "Good morning", "Hello everyone", "Thank" you etc. is not necessary here. Just ask your question. And upvote useful comments and  answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fgets` can append to the entered sequence of characters the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

You need to remove it before calling `strcmp` like for example

```
test[ strcspn( test, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Pay attention that it will be more safer to write

```
char name[] = "Pedro";
```

instead of

```
char name[6] = "Pedro";
```

Otherwise in general you can make a mistake counting characters in a string literal.

Also instead if this line

```
fgets(test, 25, stdin);
```

it will be better to write

```
fgets(test, sizeof( test ), stdin);
```

without using the magic number `25`.

Answer (score 2):

fgets keeps the '\n' at the end of the line, it must be removed before the comparison. Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[6] = "Pedro";
    char test[25];

    printf("Insert a name: ");
    fgets(test, 25, stdin);

    test[strcspn(test, "\n")] = '\0';

    if(!strcmp(name, test))
        puts("They are equal...");

    return 0;
}
```